# DataBase for WindowsPhone applications

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile

I am new to Windows Phone Application Development . I spent a couple of days to understand the XAML and other Libraries . I started with simple application which doesnt require any DataBase .What kind of DataBase can be used and how to connect it with the application .

or XML Processing will better

Comment: Do you want storage on the phone or in an external database on some server?

Comment: I need to store on the Phone . Let me Explain it clearly . I need to access the details from the Contact List ( Name and Number ) and need to Process it and to store the Processed data in the DatBase or XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both methods i.e. store information on a local database in your phone's isolated storage or read and save XML files.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860%28v=vs.92%29.aspx):

> With Windows Phone OS 7.1, you can store relational data in a local
>   database that resides in your application’s isolated storage
>   container. Windows Phone applications use LINQ to SQL for all database
>   operations; LINQ to SQL is used to define the database schema, select
>   data, and save changes to the underlying database file residing in
>   isolated storage.

Here is [How to: Create a Basic Local Database Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202876%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

If your requirement is simply to store data and a very complicated database design/schema is not required or simply because you are developing on Windows Phone OS 7.0. You can use XML as can be found here:

[Read and Save XML files using XmlSerializer](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-XML-files)

Comment: Let me go with XML Manipulation first